# Autocomplete does not turn off

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form:

```
<%= form_tag("/users/submit_users_form", method: "post", class: "form-container", :autocomplete => 'off')
```

which renders as:

```
<form class="form-container" autocomplete="off" action="/users/submit_users_form" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
```

and then I have the text_field_tag and password_field_tag:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'your_email', '', :required => true, :autocomplete => 'off' %>
<%= password_field_tag 'your_password', '', :required => true, :autocomplete => 'off' %>
```

which render as:

```
<input type="text" name="your_email" id="your_email" value="" required="required" autocomplete="off">

<input type="password" name="your_password" id="your_password" value="" required="required" autocomplete="off">
```

(even the password value is set to "")

So I have set all to autocomplete off. Now when I visit the website I get this:

[image]

Any clue why the autocomplete is still on?

Answer (score 0):

The chances are you have saved your login details to the browser for said site URL therefore it will always be in there by default. If you remove them from your browser stored passwords area it should be fine as you have autocomplete="off" in the `<form>` tag.

Comment: I have stored several times on several occasions my email and password. The issue is that on another form on that website that does not related with the your_email and your_password inputs I get these values filled in as well. I assume there is a way to make this go away. Maybe name the form or something like that.